# Next.js: Render dynamic pages customized based on requesting host

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

I want to render dynamic next.js pages with custom content / style based on the domain which requests the page. 
Basically run one next.js app under multiple domains.

I know that I have to do some sort of custom routing, but don't know exactly how and how I can pass the host information to the requested page, so it fetches the matching data from a database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to verify this in your `pages/_app.jsx` file `static getInitialProps(context)` method and use the `context` to verify where the request is coming from then return a flag to the component.

Example:

```
// pages/_app.js

import app from 'next/app';

export default class MyApp extends app {
  static getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = app.getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx });

    if (ctx.req.headers.host.match(/localhost/)) {
      pageProps = {
        ...pageProps,
        renderFrom: 'mydomain',
      }
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <section id="app">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I call `app.getInitialProps` to mimic the `next/app` component behaviour as in the source code [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_app.js#L11-L14)

In your `pages/index.js` you will have access to `props.renderFrom` and there you can display data.

```
// pages/index.js

import React from 'react'

const Home = props => (
  <div>
    Rendering content for domain: {props.renderFrom}
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

Since you're verifying where the request comes from in `_app.js` this property will be available in all your containers (pages) so you can have the same routing for your application and just render data differently.

Tip: You could also use `next-routes` to manage the routing for the application, it's better than the out next comes with, and in here you have a custom server where you can manage your traffic as well.

Hopefully this helps you and points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an example of hosting **multiple domains on the same Next.js site** (while maintaining **multiple languages** and static site generation/SSG), using Next.js’ i18n system:

https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-multi-domain-locale