# Wrapping a dynamic custom skin around a Next.js app in server-render phase

Tags: reactjs, next.js, multi-tenant

> I did look through the similar questions and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54688864/751), but the answer there isn't, at least by itself, dynamic enough for my needs.

Similar to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54688864/751), I am attempting to put together a multi-tenant application with a different skin per property. However, the answer given in the above question assumes that the various skin resources can be hard-coded into the application. That would be fine if we were talking about 2 or 3 skins, but my application will need to support dozens at launch and probably tens of thousands in its lifetime (each property can create multiple skins for different campaigns).

I have an API where I can request the skin, which is currently a long string of HTML with a token embedded indicating where the application contents should be rendered into the skin (e.g. `{{body}}`).

One of the things I'll need to do is inject some `<link>` tags into the `<Head>` element to pull in some external CSS. If React.Fragment supports attributes (like `__dangerouslySetInnerHTML`), I haven't been able to figure out how. If it's possible, that might be one way.

I'll run into the same problem when I want to inject some pre-application and post-application content into the body of the page, too.

Since I want the skin to be rendered server-side on the first request and then be static until the tab is closed, it makes sense to do this in `pages/_document.js`. After that, I'm kind of lost for what to do next. Parsing the string that contains the skin content is easy enough, but how do I intermingle that raw HTML with React components?